# how to split files from error.log file of apache server while reading file line by line continuously?

Tags: file, apache2, sed, split, logfile

I have done like this but I am having trouble with shellscript I have written. I am confused with tail command functionality and also when I see output of error.log on terminal it shows lines with 'e' deleted from words.

I have written like this please guide me how can I get my problem solved. I want to read this error.log file line by line and during reading lines I want to split fixed number of lines to small files with suffix i.e log-aa,log-ab,... I did this using split command. After splitting I want to filter lines with GET or POST word in them using regex and store this filtered lines into new file. After this store gets completed I need to delete all these log-* files.

I have written like this:

```
enter code here
processLine(){
  line="$@"
  echo $line
  $ tail -f $FILE
}
FILE="/var/log/apache2/error.log"
if [ "$1" == "/var/log/apache2/error.log" ]; then
   FILE="/dev/stdin"
else
   FILE="$1"
   if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
   echo "$FILE : does not exists"
   exit 1
   elif [ ! -r $FILE ]; then
   echo "$FILE: can not read"
   exit 2
   fi
fi
#BAKIFS=$IFS
#IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"$FILE"
#sed -e 's/\[debug\].*\(data\-HEAP\)\:\/-->/g' error.log > /var/log/apache2/error.log.1
while read -r line
do
 processLine $line
done
exec 0<&3
IFS=$BAKIFS
logfile="/var/log/apache2/error.log"
pattern="bytes"
# read each new line as it gets written
# to the log file
#tail -1 $logfile 
tail -fn0 $logfile | while read line ; do
# check each line against our pattern
echo "$line" | grep -i "$pattern" 
#sed -e 's/\[debug\].*\(data\-HEAP\)\:/-->/g' error.log >/var/log/apache2/error.log
split -l 1000 error.log log-  
FILE2="/var/log/apache2/log-*"
if [ "$1" == "/var/log/apache2/log-*" ]; then
   FILE2="/dev/stdin"
else
   FILE2="$1"
   if [ ! -f $FILE2 ]; then
   echo "$FILE : does not exists"
   exit 1
   elif [ ! -r $FILE2 ]; then
   echo "$FILE: can not read"
   exit 2
   fi
fi
BAKIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"$FILE2"
while read -r line
do
 processLine $line
 echo $line >>/var/log/apache2/url.txt
done
exec 0<&3
IFS=$BAKIFS
find . -name "var/log/apache2/logs/log-*.*" -delete
done
exit 0
```

The below code deletes files after reading and splitting error.log but when I put tail -f $FILE it stops deleting files I want to delete log-* files after it reaches last line of error.log file: 
    enter code here

```
processLine(){
line="$@" 
echo $line
}
FILE=""
if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
FILE="/dev/stdin"
else
FILE="$1"
# make sure file exist and readable
if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
echo "$FILE : does not exists"
exit 1
elif [ ! -r $FILE ]; then
echo "$FILE: can not read"
exit 2                                     
fi
fi
#BAKIFS=$IFS
#IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
exec 3<&0
exec 0<"$FILE"
while read -r line
do
processLine $line
split -l 1000 error.log log-
cat log-?? | grep "GET\|POST" > storefile 
#tail -f $FILE
done 
rm log-??
exec 0<&3 
#IFS=$BAKIFS
exit 0
```

Comment: please format your code as code.  See those little icons above the empty box where you type your text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems unnecessarily long and complex, and the logic is unclear. It should not have been allowed to grow this big without working correctly.

Consider this:

```
split -l 1000 error.log log-
cat log-?? | grep "GET\|POST" > storefile
rm log-??
```

Experiment with this. If these three commands do what you expect, you can add more functionality (e.g. using paths, checking for the existence of `error.log`), but don't add code until you have this part working.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for this but I am still not getting what to remove from my code I pasted here as when I used three commands it is not working for deleting files immediately after storing filtered output to new file

Comment: @Akash Panchal: It is not working? Give us more information. Does it not delete the files? Does it delete some but not all? Does it delete the wrong files? Does it delete the correct ones but not soon enough?

Comment: It works to some extent it stores data from log-* file to new file but after storing data it is not able to delete log-* files and I also want to remove a particular string from every line from this new file so I tried like this but it is not working

Comment: Try `rm log-*` by hand and see if that works, then go from there. And don't worry about removing the string yet-- DON'T ADD THINGS UNTIL THIS PIECE WORKS.

Comment: HI I WROTE LIKE THIS IT CREATES SPLIT FILES AND ALSO DELETES THEM BUT IT FAILS TO ADD FILTERED OUTPUT TO NEW FILE:

Comment: I know how to filter the output. Don't be rude.

Comment: @Beta I am sorry I am new to all these so I am facing difficulties if any mistake from me forgive me as I am not an experienced programmer after your guidance my code looks good and it works well for deleting file unless I use tail -f $FILE to read file continuously. If I can able to delete files after I reach last line of error.log it will solve my problem because when I refresh my browser page it adds new lines to error.log as I configured apache2 with dump_io module

Comment: To remove a string, pipe the output through `sed s/string//`. And if you are adding lines to the log continuously then there is no last line, so you must rethink the design.